# Pointers in deletion AVL tree

Tags: c++, pointers

I have been trying to make a balanced binary search tree and currently am making a delete function.
And the way im trying to delete elements worked in rotation functions.

Here is the rotation function:

```
void rightRotation(Object** currentNode)
    {
        auto child = (*currentNode)->leftChild;
        auto c_bf = child->getBalanceFactor();

        if (c_bf > 0) // RR rotation
        {
            auto originalNode = *currentNode;
            originalNode->leftChild = child->rightChild;
            child->rightChild = originalNode;
            *currentNode = child;
        }
        else // RL rotation
        {
            // -L part of the rotation
            auto originalChild = child;
            child = child->rightChild;
            (*currentNode)->leftChild = child;
            originalChild->rightChild = child->leftChild;
            child->leftChild = originalChild;
            // R- part of the rotation
            auto originalNode = *currentNode;
            originalNode->leftChild = child->rightChild;
            child->rightChild = originalNode;
            *currentNode = child;
        }
    }
```

So the function takes an address of the address of the node and replaces that address of the node with address of the new node(child).

And im trying to build a delete function around the same logic but it doesn't work and i can't understand why.

Here is the delete function:

```
void del(Object** node)
    {
        if ((*node)->leftChild == NULL and (*node)->rightChild == NULL) // current node is a leaf
        {
            delete (*node);
            (*node) = NULL;

            //return;
        }
        else if ((*node)->rightChild == NULL)
        {
            auto newNode = (*node)->leftChild;
            delete (*node);
            (*node) = newNode;

            //return;
        }
        else if((*node)->leftChild == NULL)
        {
            auto newNode = (*node)->rightChild;
            delete (*node);
            (*node) = newNode;

            //return;
        }
        else // we have both childs 
        {
            // find the smallest element bigger than the current node
            // it will be the leftest element of the right child

            auto replacementNode = (*node)->rightChild;
            while (replacementNode->leftChild != NULL)
                replacementNode = replacementNode->leftChild;

            auto copy = new Object(*replacementNode);
            copy->leftChild = (*node)->leftChild;
            copy->rightChild = (*node)->rightChild;
            delete (*node);
            (*node) = copy;
            del(&replacementNode);
        }

        balance();
    }
```

I tried debugging and the address that gets into delete function is not the same as the address i get from &this->root->leftChild (im trying to delete this node)

[the whole code](https://pastebin.com/epgYhGGK)

Comment: No parent pointers?

Comment: @doug65536 no. i made rotation functions work without parent pointers so i decided not to use them at all

Comment: How do you plan on traversing to the next and previous item, in order?

Comment: why do i need to go up ?

Comment: In your recursive call to `del`, you use `&replacementNode`, but that is a *copy* that you're taking the address of.

Comment: i guess using recursion

Comment: It would be better if you showed a test case that failed, instead of us guessing what might be wrong.

Comment: [Going to the next item in a binary search tree](https://github.com/doug65536/dgos/blob/master/kernel/lib/basic_set.h#L1640)

Comment: @cigien on the first call the address that gets fed into my function is not the right address. `&this->root->rightChild` (im trying to delete this) in the memory thing window gives a different address

Comment: Then you need to show how you are calling the function. Make a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: [here is the whole code](https://pastebin.com/epgYhGGK)

Comment: I think i found the problem. I'm kinda stupid. My `get` function returns `Object*` and i make `auto x = get(...)` and then `del(&x)`. And for some reason `auto x` is not `Object*` it is just `Object`. sorry for wasting your time